# What are the consequences of deleting a property in Google Search Console?

Tags: google-search-console

I plan to delete the Google Search Console property for my website. What are the consequences of doing so?

Answer (score 1):

If you delete the property from search Console. You will lose all the **past search performance data** (from which Keyword, you are getting how much impression, your SERP Rankings etc).

Apart from that, you will lose the **international targeting** (if you have set, that you want to target specific country), after deleting it will universal.

You will lose control over your site's **sitemap** contribution from your side to Google. You won't able to tell Google, which page you need to index, google will decide.

You will lose control to set **Sitelinks** for your website, which appears in Google search engine when someone search your brand name.

You won't be able to **remove any url** of your site from google, if you want.

Overall, you will be breaking the **bridge** between your site and Google.

Comment: All true.  It also might be worth saying what you won't lose.  Deleting a property won't remove your site from Google's index.  Unless you have tweaked the special setting you outlined, it shouldn't change your SEO at all.

Comment: My question is, if you then re-add the property back, will all the old data show again or will it start from scratch?